# Java: replace forEach loop with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

In the following method I want to replace the forEach loop with a stream.

```
protected Set<String> getSelectedPaths(final CheckModel<TreeItem<String>> checkModel, final LazyTreeItem root) {

      final Set<String> ceckedList = new HashSet<>();
      final List<TreeItem<String>> children = root.getChildren();
      final List<LazyTreeItem> lazyChildren = children.stream().map((item -> (LazyTreeItem) item))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

      final List<String> selectedChildren = new ArrayList<>();
      children.forEach(child -> selectedChildren.addAll(getSelectedPaths(checkModel, (LazyTreeItem) child)));

      /**
      * do sth with checkedList
      */
     return checkedList
```

the lines

```
      final List<String> selectedChildren = new ArrayList<>();
      children.forEach(child -> selectedChildren.addAll(getSelectedPaths(checkModel, (LazyTreeItem) child)));
```

should be replaced with a stream. I tried with

```
      final List<String> selectedChildren = children.stream().map(child->getSelectedPaths(checkModel, (LazyTreeItem) child)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but the compiler error "
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Set<String>> to List<String>"`
 is thrown.
Is there an opportunity to replace this forEach loop with a stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` operation is producing a `Stream<Set<String>>` (since each element of the original `Stream<TreeItem<String>>` is mapped to a `Set<String>`), which results in a `List<Set<String>>`.

In order to get a `List<String>` you need to use `flatMap`:

```
final List<String> selectedChildren = 
    children.stream()
            .flatMap(child->getSelectedPaths(checkModel, (LazyTreeItem) child).stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to collect a `Stream<Set<String>>` into a `List<String>`. This is obviously a type mismatch. You need to flatten the stream into a `Stream<String>` prior to collecting it using `.flatmap(Set::stream)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using .flatmap after Map ,

```
final List<String> selectedChildren = children.stream().map(child->getSelectedPaths(checkModel, (LazyTreeItem) child)).flatMap(child.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```